# Динамическая запись данных в XML файл

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Здравствуйте! Есть XML файл. 
***a.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <Book>
    <Name>Азбука</Name>
    <Amount>10</Amount>
    <Price>10,15</Price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Name>Букварь</Name>
    <Amount>20</Amount>
    <Price>20,25</Price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Name>География</Name>
    <Amount>30</Amount>
    <Price>30,35</Price>
  </Book>
</root>
```

Вот Windows форма. 
Пользователь нажимает кнопку Открыть XML файл, выбирает файл **a.xml**. Происходит заполнение таблицы. 
Теперь пользователь хочет добавить данные в файл **a.xml**. Он вводит данные, например:

- Математика
- 40
- 40,45

Нажимает на кнопку Записать.
[image: фото1]
В файл **a.xml** была добавлена запись. Обратите внимание, программа вместо Book вставляет Table1

```
Book генерирует Table1.
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <Book>
    <Name>Азбука</Name>
    <Amount>10</Amount>
    <Price>10,15</Price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Name>Букварь</Name>
    <Amount>20</Amount>
    <Price>20,25</Price>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <Name>География</Name>
    <Amount>30</Amount>
    <Price>30,35</Price>
  </Book>
  <Table1>
    <Name>Математика</Name>
    <Amount>40</Amount>
    <Price>40,45</Price>
  </Table1>
</root>
```

Вот код **Form1.cs**. Если я пишу в конструкторе DataTable("Book"), от генерируется ошибка (таблица с таким именем существует). Если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите. Нужно, что бы и дальше происходила запись Book, а не Table1, Table2 и т.д.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace _0006 {
 public partial class Form1 : Form {
  //путь
  string path = null;
  DataSet DS = null;

  public Form1() {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  //кнопка Открыть файл XML
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".xml;";
   openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML файл (*.xml;)|*.xml;";
   openFileDialog1.Title = "Выберите XML документ";
   openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
   if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    textBox1.Text = path;

    //создаем объект DataSet 
    DS = new DataSet("root");
    //заполняем объект DataSet из XML файла
    DS.ReadXml(path);
    //заполняем объект dataGridView 
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
   }
  }

  //кнопка Записать
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

   //создаем объект DataTable, если записываю Book, 
   //генерируется ошибка, что такая таблица существует в файле XML
   //DataTable DT = new DataTable("Book");
   DataTable DT = new DataTable();

   //создаем колонки с названиями
   DT.Columns.Add("Name");
   DT.Columns.Add("Amount");
   DT.Columns.Add("Price");

   //заполняем строку таблицы
   DT.Rows.Add(new object[] { textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text });

   //добавляем объект DataTable
   DS.Tables.Add(DT);

   //записываем в XML файл
   DS.WriteXml(path);

   //очитска полей ввода
   textBox2.Clear();
   textBox3.Clear();
   textBox4.Clear();
   //передаем фокус первому полю ввода
   textBox2.Focus();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: На сколько я понял `Table1` - берется из `DataTable.TableName`. Укажите `DataTable.TableName="Book"`

Comment: DataTable.'TableName="Book"', это одно и то же если 'DataTable DT = new DataTable("Book");'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В DataSet'е у вас уже есть таблица с именем Book. Её и используйте для добавления новых данных; не нужно создавать ещё одну таблицу.

В методе `button2_Click` вместо

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
```

напишите

```
DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0]; // или Tables["Book"];
```

И удалите строки

```
DT.Columns.Add("Name");
DT.Columns.Add("Amount");
DT.Columns.Add("Price");

DS.Tables.Add(DT);
```

Comment: Уважаемый Alexander Petrov! Спасибо Вам! Только еще нужно удалить `DT.Columns.Add("Name");DT.Columns.Add("Amount");DT.Columns.Add("Price");`, потому что на этапе выполнения происходит ошибка, столбец с именем Name уже принадлежит этой таблице

Comment: @Anton - вы правы, я исправил код.

Comment: Уважаемый @Alexander Petrov! Еще раз Вам большое спасибо!